# Error to read file from C drive with fs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use the following code to read txt file from my C drive and I got error

```
fs = require('fs')


    var path = require('path');

    var filePath = path.join(__dirname, '‪C://nodeTest//test.txt');
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

    });
```

in addition I try like following with the same error

```
fs.readFile('‪C://nodeTest//test.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

    });
```

error is

```
Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\nodeTest\test']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
```

My project is under the following path

```
C:\Users\C015869\WebstormProjects\myApp\server.js
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can only read from the webserver. If the file isn't somewhere in the webserver directory or subdirectories you can't read it. If the webserver directory is `nodeTest` then just use:

```
fs = require('fs')

var path = require('path');

var filePath = path.join(__dirname, '‪test.txt');
fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

});
```

Comment: i've tried it without success I see the file in C drive but when I use fs.existsSync('‪C://nodeTest//test.txt') I got false...any idea?

Comment: Can you update your question to show where the file is in relation to your parent node file (app.js).

Comment: Done I use the following path and I call to the fs inside my root folder server.js C:\Users\C015869\WebstormProjects\myApp\server.js

Comment: Ok so your file needs to be in `C:\Users\C015869\WebstormProjects\myApp\` somewhere if you want to open it. For security reasons node.js won't go looking around your OS for files.

Comment: Ok so if I put it under test folder like myapp/test/myfile.txt how should I call it?can you edit your post with the answer

Comment: `path.join(__dirname, '‪test/test.txt');`

Comment: "If the file isn't somewhere in the webserver directory or subdirectories you can't read it." That statement is absolutely false... and the OP didn't even mention webservers

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure the file exist with fs.existsSync('‪C://nodeTest//test.txt')
- Make sure you have admin privilege. If you are on windows run Command Line as Administrator
- Use single slash: var filePath = 'C:/nodeTest/test.txt'; or var filePath = path.join(__dirname, '‪test.txt')

Comment: I did both and still got the issue

Comment: Use single slash: var filePath = 'C:/nodeTest/test.txt'; or var filePath = path.join(__dirname, '‪/test.txt');

Comment: It didnt file the file and I see it in my C drive,any idea? the fs.existsSync('‪C://nodeTest//test.txt') return false to one slash and two...

Comment: I try something like var filePath = path.join(__dirname, '/test1.txt');

var exist1 = fs.existsSync(filePath);

if(!exist1){
  console.log(exist1);
}

Comment: Now I got true but still not able to read the file should I do something in addition ?

Comment: Try fs.readFile(filePath, {encoding: 'utf8'}, function (err,data)